# Neo4J - How to retrieve START_ID, END_ID and ID from a relationship?

Tags: neo4j

If I query a relationship in my database like below

```
MATCH (n)-[t]-[n] RETURN t
```

I get the following output:

```
{
  "identity": 423006861,
  "start": 89091471,
  "end": 278664,
  "type": "RELATION",
  "properties": {
     "value": 7.0
  }
}
```

How can I access the identity, start, end and type values?

`[...] RETURN t.start` just gives me `null` which is clearly not right...

I have the feeling that only the `properties` part can be accessed. Is this true? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following functions are available on relationships :

- `startNode()`
- `endNode()`
- `id()`

So,

```
MATCH (n)-[t]-[n]
RETURN
id(startNode(t)) AS startNodeId,
id(endNode(t)) AS endNodeId,
id(t) AS relationshipId
```

**Update for Neo4j 5**

In Neo4j 5, a new type of id was introduced, named `elementId`, the follwing query can also be used alternatively.

```
MATCH (n)-[t]-[n]
RETURN
elementId(startNode(t)) AS startNodeId,
elementId(endNode(t)) AS endNodeId,
elementId(t) AS relationshipId
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this smoothly did the trick!